# Sending huge message from HTTP server to an angular client

Tags: http

From a win32 HTTP server I have to send a big (~32MB) message to an angular based client running in chrome.
Must I use Websocket for this purpose ?

Or should I use Server-sent-events (SSE) ?

What are my alternatives ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Answer (score 0):

Neither Websocket nor SSE are for sending large messages specifically and it makes sense to use specifically for solving this problem.

HTTP works perfectly fine with large responses, even if it's gigabytes. Try it. If you run into problems report back here with detailed explanations of what failed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Upon client request, server must send huge (~32MB) buffer periodically (~20msec) till client ask to stop. How this can be handled on the client side ?